# Doctrine2 and Postgres : Invalid input syntax for boolean : ""

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
    SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 
    ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: ""
    500 Internal Server Error - PDOException
```

It's the error message cause by Doctrine2 (2.2-DEV) and i'm afraid it's that bug which appeared again: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1394

The query which causes this error is as follows:

```
public function getFindAllNonOthersQueryBuilder()
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.isOther = :isOther')
        ->setParameter('isOther', false);
}
```

The field isOther is mapped this way :

```
/**
 * @var boolean $isOther
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isOther", type="boolean")
 */
protected $isOther = false;
```

What's happening in here?
I've checked the type in the postgres database and it's a `boolean` too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `Literal` expression. It is related with [issue #DDC-1683](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1683)

My sample code:

```
$q->andWhere($q->expr()->eq('item.published', $q->expr()->literal(true)));
```

Answer (score 7):

I did some more googling as I have the same issue and I found the solution through the [FOSMessageBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/commit/d99018cff717f694d6ab1fcea000ec5e791e6a29), if you add '\PDO::PARAM_BOOL' to your setParameter it works, like so:

```
$qb->setParameter('isOther', false, \PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

**Solution:** Use **0** instead of **false**:

```
...
->setParameter('isOther', 0);
```

Comment: Yeah, 'false' seems to be ok too but i wanna know WHY ?